# How to explain the Schwinger Limit?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, non-linear-systems, pair-production

I have read that the [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) is the limit after which the electromagnetic field is expected to become nonlinear.

1. Is there more to what this limit is?
2. What does this practically means?
3. What is expected to happen after approaching that limit and most importantly beyond that?

Answer (score 1):

It is an idealized limit. The idealization is in assuming a possibility of creating a strong electric field and see the particle-antiparticle being born. In practice the electric field is created by separated charges, like in a Van de Graaff device; however in much more weaker electric field the atoms in an imperfect vacuum (or on electrodes) get ionized, so the vacuum "breaks" well before the Schwinger's limit with creating positive and negative charges moving in such a way that "neutralizes" (decreases) the original electric field.

Answer (score -1):

All we know is that with two lasers with a combined energy of the Schwinger limit hitting each other, electrons and positrons will be created.

Comment: Welcome to Physics S.E. and it's great you try contributing. Note however that good answers shall be more elaborated than a mere phrase. Besides, content-wise, your statement is not correct: what matters here is that **virtual** electron-positron pairs are created, as exemplified by the diagram on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit).